# How do U handle "paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)"

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dpkg, cuda

```
(base) yerim@yerim:~$ sudo apt-get install openslide-tools
[sudo] password for yerim: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 openslide-tools : Depends: libopenslide0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
(base) yerim@yerim:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 ubuntu-web-launchers
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
Recommended packages:
  libnvcuvid1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
46 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/263 MB of archives.
After this operation, 734 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 192999 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-cuda-dev (9.1.85-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried force overwrite but it did not work and every time when I tried to install something same thing happened. Always broken pipe error shows up. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with two packages trying to maintain the same files:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1
```

Something about the CUDA package is in conflict with `libcublas` - this is a problem with packages so you should file bugs in the given packages for cublas - unless you need cublas you might just want to use CUDA here.